# Using highcarts in react native and getting the error

Tags: react-native, highcharts

I have installed npm install @highcharts/highcharts-react-native in my react native project and i also added the hcscript in metro.config.js file.

Iam getting the error of
Failed to fetch scripts or layout. The method or property expo-file-system.readDirectoryAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?

Comment: Are your app a bare React Native one, or using the Expo platform? I'm asking because when trying to use that wrapper without the Expo, you also need to configure your project like it's described here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native#general-prerequisites

Comment: I am using a bare React native one.
i have installed the react-native-unimodules and done the setup as per the document.
Now android is working properly but in ios I am getting the error of 'React/RCTImageLoaderProtocol.h' file not found.
Version of react native is 0.60.5 and react is 16.8.6

Comment: Can i need to update the react native version to the latest one?

Comment: Could you somehow provide me with minimal project (e.g GitHub repo) where the problem is noticeable? It would be much more convenient to work on real example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to use this package: `@highcharts/highcharts-react-native` you should first install `react-native-unimodules` which is a set of native dependencies used at the core of `@highcharts/highcharts-react-native`  as
they built the package on top of expo not  bare react native.
it is going to require you to make heavy edits in the native ios and android files such as appDelegate.m in ios and more alike files. 
However, you should notice this package is deprecated as per the official page, and there is no reliable alternative!